# QT QUdpSocket прием дейтаграммы broadcast

Tags: c++, qt, сокет

В своей программе отправляю на устройство последовательность байт(`68, 1, 0`). Устройство отвечает последовательностью байт(`68, 1, 0`). Все это я вижу в программе WireShark. Но не могу принять пакет т.к. не происходит bind с адресом `192.168.0.255:1104`. Кто может подсказать, как это сделать?
П.С. уже облазил весь QT ассистант, но ответа не нашел.
UPDATE новый код программы (это тестовый код, просто чтобы разобраться с работой с сокетами):

```
#include "UDP.h"

UDP_Manager::UDP_Manager()
{
    QHostAddress address("192.168.0.104");

    Udp_Socket = new QUdpSocket(this);
    bool Is_Bound = Udp_Socket->bind(QHostAddress::Any, 1104);

    QByteArray Data;
    Data.resize(3);
    Data[0] = 68;
    Data[1] = 1;
    Data[2] = 0;
    Udp_Socket->writeDatagram(Data, address, 1004);
    _sleep(500);
    char Buf[4];
    qint64 i = Udp_Socket->readDatagram(Buf, sizeof(Buf));
}
```

Скрин из программы WireShark:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приём broadcast'а не отличается от приёма обычных сообщений, надо только за'bind'иться на локальные порт и адрес.

Ошибки в коде выше:

Во-первых, два сокета здесь не обязательны, вполне достаточно одного (если в дальнейшем на них не будет висеть какая-то различная логика). Сокет — это дуплексная абстракция.

Во-вторых, `bind()` всегда на локальный адрес (192.168.0.11 в данном случае), если нужно слушать все локальные интерфейсы, то следует привязываться к `0.0.0.0` (он же `QHostAddress::Any`).

В-третьих,  проверка `Udp_Socket_RX->state()` свежесозданного сокета бессмысленна.

В итоге вся инициализация сильно схлопывается:

```
QHostAddress address("192.168.0.104");

Udp_Socket = new QUdpSocket(this);
Udp_Socket->bind(QHostAddress::Any, 1104);

connect(Udp_Socket_RX, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(Receive()));

QByteArray Data {68,1,0};
Udp_Socket->writeDatagram(Data, address, 1004);
```

В-четвёртых, при чтении из сокета `Address_RX` и `Port` — это выходные параметры, их надо проверять после чтения, а не задавать до.

В остальном вроде всё... должно работать...

Comment: ЗЫ: посмотри в wireshark'е, что пакет действительно Broadcast'овый, а не просто со странным адресом...

Comment: изменил код, bind срабатывает, но сигнала readyRead() все равно нет

Comment: Вынул прием из слота- принимаю ответ, но не всегда. 50/50. Как исправить?

Comment: @GeorgeTuzikov, в wireshark'е они каждый раз регистрируются? а то я знаю одну шутку про UDP... да, и изначальную версию исходного кода лучше вернуть в вопрос, а новую дописать ниже Update'ом... а то ответ не читается...

Comment: регистрируются каждый раз. Код сейчас верну

Comment: `_sleep ()` — это что такое? ответ точно успевает прилетать за эти 500 попугаев?

Comment: Это QT-шный слип, ответ прилетает, но иногда. Мне кажется, что из-за неявного айпи, ко мне прилетают пакеты и с других устройств.

Comment: @GeorgeTuzikov в Qt есть QThread::{,u,m}sleep, это явно не Qt'шное... больше похоже на что-то виндовое... по поводу пекетов — да, так и должно быть, в `readDatagram` надо передавать пустые адрес и порт и проверять, от кого получено сообщение...

Comment: Все, разобрался, в чем дело. Проблема была в устройстве, которое давало ответ. Код правильный, спасибо. Выручаешь уже второй раз, @Fat-Zer)